# Get free disk space of a Windows mount point remotely

Tags: windows, winapi, diskspace

Does anyone know of a way to get the free disk space of a Windows mount point on a remote system *without* using WMI?

For example, GetDiskFreeSpaceEx returns the following values:

```
C:\ - 29 GB
C:\MountedDir - 50 GB
```

When run remotely on a Windows 2003 server (orig_server is 2008 R2) it reports the following:

```
\\orig_server\C$ - 29 GB
\\orig_server\C$\MountedDir - 29 GB
```

Anyway to get the true space of MountedDir remotely without WMI?

**[UPDATE]**
I found that if the target server AND the requesting server are both Windows 2008 R2 I get:

```
\\orig_server\C$ - 29 GB
\\orig_server\C$\MountedDir - 50 GB
```

Apparently Windows 2008 R2 (only if both are 2008?) fixes this.  Does anyone know of any documentation that confirms this and explains the boundaries of the scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the original SMB protocol does not support mount points, when both the server and client is >=NT6, they can use SMB2 which probably why it works correctly when both are Server 2008